# WP7 Live Tile text color?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to change the color of the `Title` on the Live Tile icon?

The `BackgroundImage` I used has a white background, so I can't see the `Title` right now.

An alternative is to cut the bottom of my `BackgroundImage` where the `Title` is and make it transparent if I can't change the text color, does anyone has a better solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a Tile without any Title and put the text right into the image.

That way you can use any color you want.

Answer (score 3):

The WP7 Tilt *Default* text can **NOT** be changed.

- Dark Theme is White Text
- Light Theme is Black Text

I suggest designing a Tile that looks good with both Themes

-OR-

Make two tiles and change it based on Theme